# What functor does $K(G, 1)$ represent for nonabelian $G$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

For $G$ an abelian group, the Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(G, n)$ represents singular cohomology $H^n(-; G)$ with coefficients in $G$ on the homotopy category of CW-complexes. If $n > 1$, then $G$ must be abelian, but for $n = 1$ there are also Eilenberg-Maclane spaces for $G$ nonabelian, so one might imagine that they represent some kind of nonabelian cohomology $H^1(-; G)$. Is this functor known by a better name, and what's known about it? In particular,

- Does it have an alternate definition along the lines of the usual definition of singular cohomology?
- Is there a universal coefficient theorem for it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

K(G,1) aka BG classifies G-bundles — i.e. G-coverings, if G is discrete. (Details  can be found e.g. in May's [Concise Course in Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf).)

Usual definition of Cech cohomology works for $H^1(X;G)$ even in non-abelian case (but it's just the usual cocycle definition of G-bundle).

As for universal coefficient theorem, even if $H_1(X;\mathbb Z)$ is trivial, $H^1(X;G)$ needn't be; but (if G is discrete) $H^1(X;G)=\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X);G)/\text{conjugation}$ (reference: [Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), 1B.9). (But if one wishes to consider BG for general G, things get worse — "$H^1$" is no longer defined by 2-skeleton of X. Perhaps, AHSS from cohomology to K-theory can be viewed as kind of "universal coefficient spectral sequence" for $G=U=\lim U(n)$.)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference? This material doesn't seem to be covered in Hatcher, for example.

Comment: Also, I googled http://www-math.mit.edu/~mbehrens/18.906/prin.pdf -- which looks good

Comment: shouldn't this classify principal G-bundles?